# Change the name of properties in an Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is aggregate function, I need to get all the products that belong to each user in the collection, so far I have achieved that:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
{
  $lookup:{
   from:"products",
   localField: "id",
   foreignField: "user_id",
   as: "user_products"
  }
},
{
  $project:{
    name:1,
    user_products:{NAME:1,PRICE:1}
  }
}
```

]).pretty();

**There result for this is:**

```
[
{
  name:"Felipe Blanco",
  user_products:[
    {NAME:"LAPTOP",PRICE:10},
    {NAME:"CAR",PRICE:10}
  ]

}
```

]

**Now what i need is to change the name of the properties of the objects inside the *use_products array*, like this:**

```
[
{
  name:"Felipe Blanco",
  user_products:[
    {product_name:"LAPTOP",product_price:10},
    {product_name:"CAR",product_price:10}
  ]

}
```

]

Comment: @SamipSuwal I suppose so, and honestly I just didn't even think to look. It may be noted at the time that answer ( mine actually ) was written you could not do things like `"$user_products.NAME"` to get a property within an array at all. I did make a note of why you don't want to do that in the answer here, plus added some more goodies from recent versions :). As for the duplicate, I'll leave it to someone else to judge.

Comment: @SamipSuwal It frankly should not matter if it is marked as a duplicate or not. The vast majority of posts marked as such simply remain on the site, just with a prominent link to the other question. Both would then be essentially searchable and both would have that prominent fixture in the **Related** sidebar on the site. Which frankly, more people should actually look at when viewing or posting questions. Like I said, I could mark and close it myself, but for now I'll leave that decision to someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
  { "$lookup":{
    "from": "products",
    "localField": "id",
    "foreignField": "user_id",
    "as": "user_products"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "user_products": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$user_products",
        "as": "up",
        "in": {
          "product_name": "$$up.NAME",
          "product_price": "$$up.PRICE" 
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator iterates the array and return the result in the `"in"` expression. Since these are now "individual members" from the array, you can use the explicit name as variable and re-assign to the new key names.

You **cannot** for instance assign the variables directly like:

```
{ "$project": { "user_products": { "product_name": "$user_products.NAME" } }} }
```

Because `"$user_products"` refers to the "array", and MongoDB interprets this as *"an array of the specified property"*, which is not what you want and why you use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) instead.

The result of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) is:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594876e07011be147496f076"),
        "name" : "Felipe Blanco",
        "user_products" : [
                {
                        "product_name" : "LAPTOP",
                        "product_price" : 10
                },
                {
                        "product_name" : "CAR",
                        "product_price" : 10
                }
        ]
}
```

---

### Fancy Version

If you don't like hardcoding all the keys and you want to prefix and "lowercase" the existing names, then MongoDB 3.4 adds the `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` pipeline functions that allow you to do this in a more dynamic way:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
  { "$lookup":{
    "from": "products",
    "localField": "id",
    "foreignField": "user_id",
    "as": "user_products"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "user_products": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$user_products",
        "as": "up",
        "in": {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$map": {
              "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$up" },
              "as": "p",
              "in": {
                "k": { "$concat": [ "product_", { "$toLower": "$$p.k" } ] },
                "v": "$$p.v"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which is a lot more long winded than simply specifying each key, but it does have it's uses if such "prefixing" is your actual intent.